# WCF REST services IErrorHandler

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF REST service which is consumed on the client by the classical :

```
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I want to intercept any errors that appear in the service and deliver them to the client. By default behavior, when an exception occurs in the service an faultexception is thrown and the channel is faulted, therefore on the client I receive a Bad request.
I want to be able to return the client the stackstrace and override the behaviour not to fault the channel.
For that I have implemented the IErrorHandler

```
 public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {

            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {

            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, string.Empty, String.Format("An unknown error has occurred. The error identifier "), new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string)));
            fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
            fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

        }
}
```

the question is even if I register this on the service, I can debug the errorhandler, but the channel is still faulted so I still receive a bad request in the client.
I use the following factory for the client:

```
protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var host =  base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

            ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });     
            return host;


        }
```

The question is how can I prevent the channel from getting faulted in the errorhandler.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  I have the same situation and I set the fault also in the ProvideFault method.  The only thing I can think of is that I am not seeing you create a FaultException from which you'd call CreateMessageFault().

Here is an example:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
{
  // we don't want the communication channel to fault, so we'll provide a general purpose fault with the exception provided.
  var fe = new FaultException(error.Message);
  MessageFault msg = fe.CreateMessageFault();
  fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, msg, "YourActionNamespace");
}
```